# Build Path Problems

Tags: android, eclipse

When i bulid the android program, i found these errors happening. Can ayone help me fix this?
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/home/harikrishnan/project/For_Jms/Common/AppCommon/bin/appcommon.jar'    GenericTransport        Build path  Build Path Problem

Comment: have you jar file in libs folder of your project......?

Answer (score 1):

> The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library
>   '/home/harikrishnan/project/For_Jms/Common/AppCommon/bin/appcommon.jar'

App can't find your `appcommon.jar`, probably you added incorrect path to your `.jar` file.

Check your path at first if is right.